# How to set Kubernetes config map and secret to mongodb environment variables

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I am trying to set the two `env` variables of mongo namely - `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` using `kubernetes` **ConfigMap**  and **Secret** as follows:

When I don't use the config map and password, i.e. I hardcode the username and password, it works, but when I try to replace it with configmap and secret, it says

> 'Authentication failed.'

my username and password is the same, which is `admin`

Here's the `yaml` definition for these obects, can someone help me what is wrong?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-username
data:
  username: admin
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-password
data:
  password: YWRtaW4K  
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodbtest
spec:
  # serviceName: mongodbtest
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodbtest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodbtest
        selector: mongodbtest
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodbtest
        image: mongo:3       
        # env:
        #   - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
        #     value: admin
        #   - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
        #     value: admin
        env:
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-username
                key: username
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-password
                key: password
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to find the solution after hours, it is not something I did from kubernetes side, it is when I did `base64` encode.

The correct way to encode is with following command:

```
echo -n 'admin' | base64
```

and this was the issue with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD : password
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongo-cred
  namespace: default
```

inject it to deployment like

```
envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: mongo-cred
```

the deployment will be something like

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodbtest
spec:
  # serviceName: mongodbtest
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodbtest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodbtest
        selector: mongodbtest
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodbtest
        image: mongo:3    
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: mongo-cred
```

if you want to save the data in secret, the secret is best practice to store data with encryption base64 and sensitive data.

```
envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: mongo-cred
```

you can create the secret with

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: YWRtaW4K #base 64 encoded
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD : YWRtaW4K
kind: secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: mongo-cred
  namespace: default
```

Comment: I want password to be a `Secret` object and besides this is not working.

Comment: just use the secretRef instead of config.i have updated the answer you can please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment yaml is fine, just change `spec.containers[0].env` to `spec.containers[0].envFrom`:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodbtest
        image: mongo:3       
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: mongodb-username
          - secretRef:
              name: mongodb-password
```

That will put all keys of your secret and configmap as environment variables in the deployment.